# Fourier sine series over $[0,\pi]$ vs over $[-\pi,\pi]$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, summation, fourier-series

So from what I understand, on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$, only even functions have cosine series and only odd functions have sine series. But then on $[0,\pi]$ functions have cosine and sine series? Why is this? And why does the same formula for finding the series work?

Comment: The integral must be considered within a period of the function you are expanding in sines and cosines (both trig functions with the same period as for the function). If a function is even in the interval you choose it will have an even expansion, and vice-versa for the odd case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is that for any function $f(x)$ on $[0,\pi]$ we can pretend that $f$ is an even or odd function on $[-\pi,\pi]$ by defining $f(x) := f(-x)$ or $f(x):=-f(-x)$ for $-\pi \leq x <0$. Then we just take the sine or cosine series for the extended version of $f$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ and restrict it to $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: Ah, thanks! that makes perfect sense.

Comment: Is it necessary to explain that I'm doing an odd or even extension of the function if I'm doing a problem like this?

Comment: It is not absolutely necessary to mention. As you mentioned, only odd functions have sine series and only even functions have cosine series on $[-\pi,\pi]$, so if you want the cosine series of $f$ on $[0,\pi]$ it must be that you are considering the even extension to $[-\pi,\pi]$. However, if this is homework, you may do well to explain why an odd/even extension is necessary. If this is not homework, a working mathematician will know which extension you took.